# Java sax parser bug

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I am using java sax parser and i override

```
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    value = new String(ch, start, length);
```

in some case array ch contains qName of element but not contains entire value.

Example:

```
ch = [... , x, s, d, :, n, a, m, e, >, 1, 2, 3]
```

but the real value of xsd:name is 123456789

**EDIT**

```
String responseString = Utils.getXml(url);

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
handler = new SimpleHandler();
saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseString)), handler);

List<Entit> list = handler.getList();
```

I have xml like this (ofcourse the original xml is much bigger)

```
<root>
   <el>
     <xsd:name>11111111</xsd:name>
   </el>
   <el>
     <xsd:name>22222222</xsd:name>
   </el>
   <el>
     <xsd:name>123456789</xsd:name>
   </el>
   <el>
     <xsd:name>333333333</xsd:name>
   </el>
</root>
```

i get error just for one value in xml.

How to fix that.

Comment: Can you provide code that calls the parser and the corresponding XML document?

Comment: Is it fair to say your overall question is "**How do I get the value of the element `<xsd:name>`?**"?

Comment: No i don't think so. I get values on other xmls. So i think this is some bug in java sax parser

Comment: You really want to believe that you happen to find a bug in a very common API part of technology used by thousands of programmers every day that is over a decade old? Blaming the tools gets you absolutely nowhere, it is not in your interest to want such things to be true. Blame yourself until you really have 100% proof that it is a bug, as long as it is a you-problem you can fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `characters` method does *not* necessarily return the *entire* set of characters.  You need to store the result each time `characters` is called, something like:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    sb.append(ch, start, length);
}
```

You then need to reset your `StringBuilder` (or whatever you are using) when you find an end element tag or a begin element tag or whatever the case may be.

Read the specification for [`characters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters-char:A-int-int-):

*"The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information."*

Generally, what you should do is delete the text buffer when you see `startElement` or `endElement`.  Usually you will do something with the current buffer when these are seen.